# requests.get produce empty results

Tags: python, get, screen-scraping

a code with requests.get produce empty results although in the browser the url give all the data as expected.

I am trying to scrape a page with the following script:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
url="https://sciencelatvia.lv/data/zin_personals_list?limit=100&offset=0&sort=personals_uzvards"
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
r=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

This produces [] i.e., empty results. However, the same url in browser shows full data. Nothing changes whether I use headers or not in the requests.get (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69146659/requests-get-not-returning-anything)

UPDATE: apparently the headers were the issue here, but they needed to indicate cookies. This is the code that worked:

```
import requests
url = "https://sciencelatvia.lv/data/zin_personals_list"
querystring={"limit":"100", "offset":"0", "sort":"personals_uzvards"}
payload=""
headers={"Cookie": "current_language=lv; current_context=pub"}
r=requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, params=querystring, headers=headers)
data=r.json()
print(data)
```

Here is a page that explains how to learn what headers are needed, including cookies: https://www.scraperapi.com/blog/headers-and-cookies-for-web-scraping/. By commenting out each one by one I understood that only the cookie header was needed for my purpose.

Comment: Same URL shows [] in our browser as well, if you're getting something in your browser, it might be because of cookies. Try testing the same URL in Incognito.

Comment: Indeed, you are right: this does prduce [] in incognito window. This might mean I have a different problem: I found the url while inspecting this page: https://sciencelatvia.lv/#/pub/scientific_personal/list . After it is loaded once, the full list is displayed in the above url as well

Comment: Now you know the issue, update the details in the question, if you still have any issues with its implementation.